# Eager loading child lists in LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to optimize a LINQ to SQL request so that it results in a single SQL statement. At the moment i have something like this:

**EDIT** : removed the "where" filter for clarity - also **"Id"** is a primary key in the databsse for both object types

```
hotel = (from h in db.Hotels

         let rooms = (from r in db.HotelRooms
                      where r.HotelId == h.Id
                      select new HotelRoom
                      {
                          Id = r.Id,
                          Code = r.Code,
                          Category = r.Category
                      })

         select new Hotel
         {
             Id = h.Id,
             Name = h.Name,
             Rooms = rooms.ToList()
         }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where the Hotel business level class is defined as:

```
public class Hotel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<HotelRoom> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

Wherein the query is using initializers to create **business** objects on the fly from the DataContext entities as the query is executed.

The problem is that obviously the `.ToList()` on the Rooms collection causes the Hotel.Rooms collection to be populated via a second query.

Is there a way to populate the Hotel.Rooms property with all the HotelRooms, without it generating additional queries?

Answer (score 0):

```
  //grab the rows from the database in direct fashion.
var joinedRows = 
(
  from h in db.Hotels
  where h.Name == name
  from hr in h.HotelRooms
  select new {HotelRow = h, HotelRoomRow = hr}
)
.ToList();

  //shape the data locally
List<Hotel> result =
  from row in joinedRows
  group row.HotelRoomRow by row.HotelRow into g
  let h = g.Key
  select new Hotel()
  {
    Id = h.Id,
    Name = h.Name,
    Rooms = (
      from r in g
      select new HotelRoom()
      {
        Id = r.Id,
        Code = r.Code,
        Category = r.Category
      }).ToList()
  };
```

Comment: Thanks - but this seems to return 1 Hotel with 1 HotelRoom, for each HotelRoom in the database. So if there are 10 hotels, with 10 rooms each - this returns 100 Hotel items with 1 Room each.

Comment: Sorry - just to clarify something - i changed the above code removing the "name ==" condition to retrieve ALL hotels rather than a specific one. That's why it's returning all hotels in the database. That's not the problem i was bringing up - the problem is still that it returns 1 hotel object for every hotelroom - with each hotel object only having 1 room.

Comment: Well when i tried that exact code in a test console app - it didn't. I had it print a line for each hotel - with the number of rooms in that hotel. It printed 1500 lines, equal to the number of rooms in total, instead of 279, the number of hotels - and each hotel had only 1 room in - nistead of displaying the 4-10 rooms it should of had.

Comment: Do you have a primary key for your Hotels?  Without a primary key, this code won't work.

Comment: Question modified to indicate that ID's are primary keys